# Call AsyncTask when exiting activity (Or possibly another solution?)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-drive-android-api

I am writing an app where the user writes words in an activity called `TranslateActivity`. I want to store these words on the google drive connected to the user.

I have implemented code using `AsyncTask` that is able to create files and append data to the drive and so on. However, I do not want to push data to the drive every time that the user writes a word since it takes some time. Instead I want to do the following:

When the user presses `back`, the uploading shall start in the background. However, it does not work for me. I assume that android closes the contexts and so forth and that destroys the `AsyncCall`.

The reason to why I want to do the upload when the user exits the activity is because then I know there won't be more inputs.

The code looks like

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    googleDriveWrite.execute(mAdapter.getWords());
    while(!mIsFinished){
    }
}
```

`GoogleDriveWrite` returns a `boolean` when it has finished. I don't like the attempt above, but I guess you understand what I try to do.

I am looking for a solution that either "pauses" the UI until the upload is complete, for example showing a progress bar, or something that keeps working when the activities are changing.

One possible solution would be to include a `save`-button, but I want it to work smoothly without user input.

I just found this: https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html There one can use

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;
}
```

to attach a new activity the fragment in case of rotation etc. Maybe one could do something similar to the `GoogleDriveWrite` that extends `AsyncTask`? Although `AsyncTask` does not seem to contain `onAttach(Activity activity)`.

The `Context` and `Activity` are needed in the `GoogleDriveWrite` to call for example `Drive.getDriveResourceClient(Context, GoogleSignInAccount)`, there is maybe where the problem lies?

Here is the `GoogleDriveWrite.java`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveResourceClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Metadata;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Filters;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Query;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.SearchableField;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class GoogleDriveWrite extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Words>,Void, Boolean> {
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    final public static String PARENTNAME = "TAILOREDDICTIONARY";
    public final static int MAXTIME = 15000;
    private DriveResourceClient mDriveResourceClient;
    private DriveClient mDriveClient;
    private Context mContext;
    private BaseActivity mActivity;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private GoogleSignInAccount mAccount;
    protected final static int NBROFITEMS = 6;
    protected final static String TEXTNAMES[] = {"w1.txt", "w2.txt", "score.txt", "ctr.txt", "time.txt", "isHidden.txt"};
    private GoogleDriveHelper mDriveHelper;
    String mKeyName;
    private void setUp() {
        mDriveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(mContext, mAccount);
        mDriveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(mContext, mAccount);
    }
    public GoogleDriveWrite(String keyName, GoogleSignInAccount account, Context context, BaseActivity activity){
        mKeyName = keyName;
        mAccount = account;
        mContext = context;
        mActivity = activity;
        mDriveHelper = new GoogleDriveHelper();
        setUp();
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        System.out.println("In pre execute");
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mActivity,"ProgressDialog","Wait for saving files");
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
        System.out.println("In on PosteExecute");
        mActivity.setFinishedTask(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(ArrayList<Words>... words) {
        DriveFolder rootFolder = mDriveHelper.getRootFolder(mDriveResourceClient);
        if (rootFolder == null){
            throw new IllegalStateException("rootFolder is null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("root is not null!");
        }
        // Search for parentName
        MetadataBuffer metadata = mDriveHelper.searchFolders(PARENTNAME, rootFolder, mDriveResourceClient);
        if (metadata == null){
            throw new IllegalStateException("metadata is null");
        }

        DriveFolder parentFolder = getFolderFromMeta(metadata, rootFolder, PARENTNAME);
        // Release metadatabuffer
        metadata.release();
        // Check parentFolder is not null
        if (parentFolder == null){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Parentfolder is null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("parentFolder is not null");
        }

        // Search for keyFolder
        metadata = mDriveHelper.searchFolders(mKeyName, parentFolder, mDriveResourceClient);
        DriveFolder keyFolder = getFolderFromMeta(metadata, parentFolder, mKeyName);
        if (keyFolder == null){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Keyfolder is null");
        } else {
            System.out.println(mKeyName);
            System.out.println("keyFolder is not null");
        }
        metadata.release();
        // Write new data to keyFolder
        writeFilesToData(keyFolder, words[0]);
//        progressDialog.dismiss();
        return true;
    }
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> splitData(ArrayList<Words> words) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> tmp[] = new ArrayList[NBROFITEMS];
        for (int i = 0; i < NBROFITEMS; ++i) {
            tmp[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            tmp[0].add(words.get(i).w1);
            tmp[1].add(words.get(i).w2);
            tmp[2].add(Double.toString(words.get(i).score));
            tmp[3].add(Double.toString(words.get(i).ctr));
            tmp[4].add(Double.toString(words.get(i).time));
            tmp[5].add(Boolean.toString(words.get(i).isHidden));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < NBROFITEMS; i++) {
            data.add(tmp[i]);
        }
        return data;
    }
    private void writeFilesToData(DriveFolder folder, ArrayList<Words> words){
        System.out.println("Size words: " + words.size());
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = splitData(words);
        MetadataBuffer metadata = mDriveHelper.searchTextFiles(folder, mDriveResourceClient);
        ArrayList<DriveFile> driveFiles = mDriveHelper.getDriveFiles(metadata);
        // If files do not exist we must create them
        if (driveFiles.isEmpty()){
            driveFiles = mDriveHelper.createDriveFiles(folder, mDriveResourceClient);
            for (int i = 0; i < NBROFITEMS; i++){
                appendData(driveFiles.get(i), data.get(i));
            }

        } else {
            for (Metadata m : metadata) {
                if (m.getTitle().equals(TEXTNAMES[0])) {
                    appendData(driveFiles.get(0), data.get(0));
                }
                if (m.getTitle().equals(TEXTNAMES[1])) {
                    appendData(driveFiles.get(1), data.get(1));
                }
                if (m.getTitle().equals(TEXTNAMES[2])) {
                    appendData(driveFiles.get(2), data.get(2));
                }
                if (m.getTitle().equals(TEXTNAMES[3])) {
                    appendData(driveFiles.get(3), data.get(3));
                }
                if (m.getTitle().equals(TEXTNAMES[4])) {
                    appendData(driveFiles.get(4), data.get(4));
                }
                if (m.getTitle().equals(TEXTNAMES[5])) {
                    appendData(driveFiles.get(5), data.get(5));
                }
            }
        }
        metadata.release();
    }

    private void appendData(DriveFile driveFiles, ArrayList<String> data){
        DriveContents content = mDriveHelper.getTaskResult(mDriveResourceClient.openFile(driveFiles, DriveFile.MODE_READ_WRITE));
        if (content == null){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Content is null");
        }
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = content.getParcelFileDescriptor();
        long bytesToSkip = pfd.getStatSize();
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor())) {
            // Skip to end of file
            while (bytesToSkip > 0) {
                long skipped = in.skip(bytesToSkip);
                bytesToSkip -= skipped;
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor())) {
            appendToFile(out, data);
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // [START commit_contents_with_metadata]
        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setStarred(true)
                .setLastViewedByMeDate(new Date())
                .build();
       Task<Void> commitTask = mDriveResourceClient.commitContents(content, changeSet);
       commitTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
               System.out.println("Files commits");
           }
       }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
               System.out.println("Failed to commit");
           }
       });
    }
    private void appendToFile(OutputStream out, ArrayList<String> data){
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                out.write((data.get(i) + "\n").getBytes());
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createFile(ArrayList<String> data, String fileName, DriveFolder folder){

    }



    /**
     * Search metadata for folder. If found return existing fodler. If not found create new folder in rootFolder
     * @param metadata Buffer with found folders
     * @param rootFolder Folder to create new folder in
     * @return drivefolder with name folderName
     */
    private DriveFolder getFolderFromMeta(MetadataBuffer metadata, DriveFolder rootFolder, String folderName){
        // ArrayList is empty we must create ParentFolder
        ArrayList<String> titles = mDriveHelper.getTitles(metadata);
        DriveFolder folder = null;
        if (titles.isEmpty()){
            folder = createFolder(rootFolder,folderName);
        } else {
            folder = metadata.get(0).getDriveId().asDriveFolder();
        }
        return folder;
    }

    private DriveFolder createFolder(DriveFolder folder, String fileName){
        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle(fileName)
                .setMimeType(DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE)
                .build();
        Task<DriveFolder> newFolder = mDriveResourceClient.createFolder(folder, changeSet);
        DriveFolder driveFolder = mDriveHelper.getTaskResult(newFolder);
        return driveFolder;
    }

    private void showMessage(String txt) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, txt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: how about running a service which pushes the data when onBackPressed

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: You mean this: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html Looks promising at least.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do in this case is schedule a job using the JobScheduler Api. You can create a new job requiring network connectivity to perform your job. The system will execute the job when possible according to the conditions you set.
[Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. Will take some time to make it work I guess

Comment: Accept the response if it's ok for you

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your task by starting a Service. But starting from Android O there is limitation on the duration for which Service will be allowed to run in background.

Since your task might take longer time, you can create a Foreground service and perform your task. This approach is more reliable.

If internet connection is not available when you are attempting to upload the data, you can Schedule a Job using JobScheduler. You can follow [this link](https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129) to get more info about it.

Comment: Thanks, that was valuable. I will look into it.